# My iPhone X was stolen. Will my iCloud be logged out if the person resets the iPhone using my phone's password?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone, face-id

The person who steal the iPhone knows the phone password. If they manage to reset the iPhone using my phone password, will my iCloud be logged out? Will it reset my Face ID?

I also forgot to turn on my Find My iPhone.

Comment: No.  If the person who has your iPhone and knows the password, they can change the password just like you can.  Have you changed the password yourself to something this person will not know?  Doing that now will prevent that person from changing your password.

Comment: He doesn't know my icloud/apple id pass but he knows my phone's password, sorry my question wasn't clear i edited it hehe

Comment: He could reset your Face ID since he has the password of the actual device but if Find my iPhone was turned on then he would still need your iCloud password in order to bypass the Activation Lock — see more about activation lock at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365

Comment: @PinchusG. Unfortunately I forgot to turn on the "Find my iphone" in my phone tho :(

Answer (score 5):

Did you have two factor enabled? Does the thief have access to your recovery email?

Regardless there are things to do right away regardless so don't hesitate!

Refer to the Apple Support article:

- [If your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch is lost or stolen](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201472)

> #### If Find My iPhone isn't enabled on your missing device
>
> If you didn't turn on Find My iPhone before your device was lost or stolen, you can't use it to locate your device. But you can use these steps to help protect your data:
>
> 1. Change your Apple ID password. By changing your Apple ID password, you can prevent anyone from accessing your iCloud data or using other services (such as iMessage or iTunes) from your missing device.
> 2. Change the passwords for other internet accounts on your device. This can include email accounts, Facebook, or Twitter.
> 3. Report your lost or stolen device to local law enforcement. Law enforcement might request the serial number of your device. Find your device serial number.
> 4. Report your lost or stolen device to your wireless carrier. Your carrier can disable the account, preventing phone calls, texts, and data use.
>
> Find My iPhone is the only way that you can track or locate a lost or missing device. If Find My iPhone isn't enabled on your device before it goes missing, there's no other Apple service that can find, track, or flag your device for you.

Answer (score 1):

> My iPhone X was stolen. Will my iCloud be logged out if the person resets the iPhone using my phone's password?

Your Apple ID password (not iPhone passcode) is required to reset your iPhone. So, no, your iPhone couldn't be reset using your device passcode. However, you should be worried if you are using your Apple ID password as the device password and the person attempts to enter it when asked for Apple ID password when attempting to reset your device.

The person can however disable/enable iCloud services such as Contacts/Photos/Safari/Calendar sync etc. with access to device passcode.

> Will it reset my Face ID?

It is also possible for them to remove Face ID data with access to device passcode.